# How do I fill data into Float64Array within this ArrayBuffer setting

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I've this raw data:

```
var x = [25];
var y = [0.004011332988739014, 0.0027810593601316214, 0.0015301937237381935, 0.0009717916836962104];
```

And I want to put them into this ArrayBuffer:

```
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(24);
var f64s = new Float64Array(h, 0, 1);
var f32s = new Float32Array(h, 1 * 4);
```

I can fill data into Float32Array with this method:

```
f32s.set(y)
```

How do I set value of array x into Float64Array with methods similar to above.
So I can get something like this:

```
new ArrayBuffer([25, 0.004011332988739014, 0.0027810593601316214, 0.0015301937237381935, 0.0009717916836962104]);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var f64s = new Float64Array(x.length + y.length);
f64s.set(x, 0);
f64s.set(y, x.length);
```